# button_to_remote using jQuery and Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

Is this possible given the `button_to_remote` function seems to be defined as a Prototype helper? I've replaced my `/public/javascripts/rails.js` with the jQuery driver.

When I try to use `button_to_remote` I get the error `undefined method 'button_to_remote' for #<#<Class:0x000001078d7090>:0x0000010789ad20>`

If this is not possible using `button_to_remote`, how can I accomplish the same thing using jQuery + Rails 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= button_to "Do Something", 
              { :controller => :somecontroller, :action=> :something }, 
              { :remote => true } 
 %>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you specify the controller that responds to the action?

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, though I have not tested it ;)